# Use jsoup to parse XML - prevent jsoup from "cleaning" <link> tags

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jsoup

In most case, I have no problem with using jsoup to parse XML. However, if there are `<link>` tags in the XML document, jsoup will change `<link>some text here</link>` to `<link />some text here`. This makes it impossible to extract text inside the `<link>` tag using CSS selector.

So how to prevent jsoup from "cleaning" `<link>` tags?

Comment: Just use ignoreContentType(true). I used this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708009/jsoup-select-returns-empty-value-but-element-does-contains-text][1]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In [jsoup 1.6.2](http://jsoup.org/news/release-1.6.2) I have added an XML parser mode, which parses the input as-is, without applying the HTML5 parse rules (contents of element, document structure, etc). This mode will keep text in a `<link>` tag, and allow multiples of it, etc.

Here's an example:

```
String xml = "<link>One</link><link>Two</link>";
Document xmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());

Elements links = xmlDoc.select("link");
System.out.println("Link text 1: " + links.get(0).text());
System.out.println("Link text 2: " + links.get(1).text());
```

Returns:

```
Link text 1: One
Link text 2: Two
```

Comment: @Jonathan Hedley : But How would you use it if you are retrieving the XML doc using JSOUP.Connect? Because that way we would not have a string version of the xml at all.

Comment: @Ashwin you would just specify the parser to use on the connection. E.g. `Jsoup.connect(url).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get()`. See the [Connection](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#parser-org.jsoup.parser.Parser-) doc

Answer (score 2):

Do not store any text inside `<link>` element - it's invalid. If you need extra information, keep it inside HTML5 `data-*` attributes. I'm sure jsoup won't touch it.

```
<link rel="..." data-city="Warsaw" />
```

Answer (score -1):

There can be a workaround for this. Before passing XML to jsoup. Transform XML file to replace all  with some dummy tag say  and do what you want to do.