# parsing html in java to extract information

Tags: java, html-parsing

I appreciate if you let me know if there is a java class to extract information from an HTML page according to an XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). I use this and is very good to parse html.
Here is an example from Jsoup site:

Example
Fetch the Wikipedia homepage, parse it to a DOM, and select the headlines from the In the news section into a list of Elements:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Comment: Thanks but how do you define xml here?

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722307/use-jsoup-to-parse-xml-prevent-jsoup-from-cleaning-link-tags

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp).

It allows you to treat HTML as XML, creating a DOM.  This allows you to use such tools as xPath

Take a look at [Java HTML Parser](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/java-html-parser.jsp) for examples

Answer (score 0):

I used HtmlUnit:

```
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa");
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("loginform");
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("os_username");
final HtmlPasswordInput pwd = form.getInputByName("os_password");
textField.setValueAttribute(jname);
pwd.setValueAttribute(jpasswd);
final HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Login").click();
```