# Scraping XML with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape an RSS feed located [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/rss/movers-and-shakers/appliances/ref=zg_bsms_appliances_rsslink).

At the moment I'm just trying to wrap my head around JSoup, so the following code is merely proof of concept (or an attempt at it, at least).

```
    public static void grabShakers(String url) throws IOException {

    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();


    desc = doc.select("title");
    links = doc.select("link");
    price = doc.select("span.price");

}
```

It grabs the title of each item perfectly. The output of each link is simply ten repeated closing link tags and it never finds any prices. I thought perhaps the CDATA was the issue, so I converted doc to html, stripped out the comments using .replace, and then converted it back to a Document for parsing to no avail. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The following code is what I'm using to print out each element:

```
for (Element src : price) {
        System.out.println(src);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **two Problems** with that feed:

1. The document contains only `<link />..actual link..` instead of full link tag
2. The description (containing the *price* tag) is *escaped* Html, which wont get parsed

**Solution:**

```
    final String url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/rss/movers-and-shakers/appliances/ref=zg_bsms_appliances_rsslink";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();


    for( Element item : doc.select("item") ) // Select all items
    {
        final String title = item.select("title").first().text(); // select the 'title' of the item
        final String link = item.select("link").first().nextSibling().toString().trim(); // select 'link' (-1-)

        final Document descr = Jsoup.parse(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(item.select("description").first().toString()));
        final String price = descr.select("span.price").first().text(); // select 'price' (-2-)

        // Output - Example
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println(link);
        System.out.println(price);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Note 1:** Workaround for the link; select the (empty) `link` tag and get the text of *next* Node (= TextNode with the actual link).

**Note 2:** Workaround for price; select the `description` tag, unescape the html, parse it and select the price. For unescaping i used [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

**Output:**
*<sub>(using link from above)</sub>*

```
#1: Epicurean Gourmet Series 20-Inch-by-15-Inch Cutting Board with Cascade Effect, Nutmeg with Natural Core
http://www.amazon.com/Epicurean-Gourmet-20-Inch-15-Inch-Cutting/dp/B003MU9PLU/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_1
$72.95

#2: GE 45600 Z-Wave Basic Handheld Remote
http://www.amazon.com/GE-45600-Z-Wave-Handheld-Remote/dp/B0013V6RW0/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_2
$3.00

#3: First Alert RD1 Radon Gas Test Kit
http://www.amazon.com/First-Alert-RD1-Radon-Test/dp/B00002N83E/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_3
$10.60

#4: Presto 04820 PopLite Hot Air Popper, White
http://www.amazon.com/Presto-04820-PopLite-Popper-White/dp/B00006IUWA/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_4
$9.99

#5: New 20 oz Espresso Coffee Milk Frothing Pitcher, Stainless Steel, 18/8 gauge
http://www.amazon.com/Espresso-Coffee-Frothing-Pitcher-Stainless/dp/B000FNK3Z4/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_5
$8.19

#6: PUR 18 Cup Dispenser with One Pitcher Filter DS-1800Z
http://www.amazon.com/PUR-Dispenser-Pitcher-Filter-DS-1800Z/dp/B0006MQCA4/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_6
$22.17

#7: Hamilton Beach 70610 500-Watt Food Processor, White
http://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-70610-500-Watt-Processor/dp/B000SAOF5S/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_7
$21.95

#8: West Bend 77203 Electric Can Opener, Metallic
http://www.amazon.com/West-Bend-77203-Electric-Metallic/dp/B00030J1U2/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_8
$35.79

#9: Custom Leathercraft 2077L Black Ski Glove, Large
http://www.amazon.com/Custom-Leathercraft-2077L-Black-Glove/dp/B00499BS9A/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_9
$8.83

#10: Cuisinart CPC-600 1000-Watt 6-Quart Electric Pressure Cooker, Brushed Stainless and Matte Black
http://www.amazon.com/Cuisinart-CPC-600-1000-Watt-Electric-Stainless/dp/B000MPA044/ref=pd_zg_rss_ms_la_appliances_10
$64.95
```

Comment: Friendly reminder for anybody coming through that jsoup does support proper XML parsing now (including a fix for the issue with `<link>` tags). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10158491/6425776