# Xml parsing using Jsoup

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, rss, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to parse xml, I have to grab links from an RSS feed such as this http://feeds.guardian.co.uk/theguardian/rss , I just need advise on how to go about this in Java, I know how to parse a single line , but how would I go about grabbing all the links?

Comment: Can you give as some more details and / or code?

Answer (score 2):

You can select links with the Jsoup selector api (see [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)).

In most cases your code will look something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); // connect to url and parse its conntent into a document

Elements elements = doc.select("your selector string"); // select your elements from the document


for( Element element : elements ) // iterate over each elements you've selected
{
    // do something
}
```

See also:

- [Cannot extract data from an XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991511/cannot-extract-data-from-an-xml/16002426#16002426)
- [Scraping XML with JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813006/scraping-xml-with-jsoup/14819274#14819274)