# Issue on parsing Html with jsoup

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse this [HTML](http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3/) using jsoup.

My code is:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(htmlUrl).timeout(1000 * 1000).get();

            Elements items = doc.select("item");
            Log.d(TAG, "Items size : " + items.size());
            for (Element item : items) {
                Log.d(TAG, "in for loop of items");

                Element titleElement = item.select("title").first();
                mTitle = titleElement.text().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "title is : " + mTitle);

                Element linkElement = item.select("link").first();
                mLink = linkElement.text().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "link is : " + mLink);

                Element descElement = item.select("description").first();
                mDesc = descElement.text().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "description is : " + mDesc);


            }
```

I am getting following output:

```
in for loop of items
D/HtmlParser( 6690): title is : Indonesian president: Some multinationals "take too much"
D/HtmlParser( 6690): link is : 
D/HtmlParser( 6690): description is : April 23 - Indonesian President Susilo Bambang Yudhoyono tells a Thomson Reuters Newsmaker event that the country welcomes foreign investment in its resources sector, but must receive a "fair share" of benefits.<div class="feedflare"> <a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3?a=NX3AY96GfGk:hAtGeOq2ESs:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3?a=NX3AY96GfGk:hAtGeOq2ESs:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3?i=NX3AY96GfGk:hAtGeOq2ESs:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3?a=NX3AY96GfGk:hAtGeOq2ESs:F7zBnMyn0Lo"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3?i=NX3AY96GfGk:hAtGeOq2ESs:F7zBnMyn0Lo" border="0"></img></a> </div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3/~4/NX3AY96GfGk" height="1" width="1"/>
```

But I want output as:

```
in for loop of items
D/HtmlParser( 6690): title is : Indonesian president: Some multinationals "take too much"
D/HtmlParser( 6690): link is : http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3/~3/KDcQe4gF-3U/62828262.mp3  
D/HtmlParser( 6690): description is : April 23 - Indonesian President Susilo Bambang Yudhoyono tells a Thomson Reuters Newsmaker event that the country welcomes foreign investment in its resources sector, but must receive a "fair share" of benefits.
```

What should I change in my code?

How to achieve my goal. Please help me!!

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems in `rss` content you fetched.

1. The `link` text is not within the `<link/>` tag but outside of it.
2. There is some `escaped html` content within the `description` tag.

PFB the modified code.

Also I found some clean html content when viewed the `URL` in `Browser`, which when parsed will make you easy to extract the desired fields. You can achieve that setting the `userAgent` as `Browser` in the `Jsoup`.  But its up to you to decide how to fetch the content.

```
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3/").timeout(0).get();
    System.out.println(doc.html());
    System.out.println("================================");
    Elements items = doc.select("item");
    for (Element item : items) {

        Element titleElement = item.select("title").first();
        String mTitle = titleElement.text();
        System.out.println("title is : " + mTitle);

        /*
         * The link in the rss is as follows
         *  <link />http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/reuters/audio/newsmakerus/rss/mp3/~3/NX3AY96GfGk/59621707.mp3 
         *  which doesn't fall in the <link> element but falls under <item> TextNode
         */
        String  mLink = item.ownText(); //  
        System.out.println("link is : " + mLink);

        Element descElement = item.select("description").first();
        /*Unescape the html content, Parse it to a doc, and then fetch only the text leaving behind all the html tags in content
         * "/" is a dummy baseURI passed, as we don't care about resolving the links within parsed content.
         */
        String  mDesc = Parser.parse(Parser.unescapeEntities(descElement.text(), false),"/" ).text(); 
        System.out.println("description is : " + mDesc);

    }
```

Comment: Could u please look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316659/unable-to-get-image-url-from-rss-feed-using-jsoup