# select this text using jsoup

Tags: parsing, jsoup

I'm wondering how I'd select only the rate value from [this page](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22SEKUSD%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys) (which is currently 0.1501):

```
public class Currency
{
    public void test() throws IOException
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22SEKUSD%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys").get();

        Elements value = doc.select("rate");
        System.out.print(value);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Currency derp = new Currency();
        derp.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this

[Use jsoup to parse XML - prevent jsoup from "cleaning" <link> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722307/use-jsoup-to-parse-xml-prevent-jsoup-from-cleaning-link-tags)

you need to use an XML parser as your url returns xml. As detailed in the answer by the author of jsoup

I think you need to check that you have access to the url by getting the link using curl on the machine you are running the java on too. eg

```
  curl "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22SEKUSD%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys" -O

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" 
       yahoo:count="1"yahoo:created="2013-07-11T20:26:10Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
  <results><rate id="SEKUSD">
      <Name>SEK to USD</Name><Rate>0.1502</Rate>
      <Date>7/11/2013</Date><Time>4:23pm</Time>
      <Ask>0.1503</Ask><Bid>0.1502</Bid>
  </rate></results>
</query>
<\!-- total: 413 -->
<\!-- engine2.yql.sg3.yahoo.com -->
```

Its probably worth mentioning that freely available finance information is delayed